# How Do You Add A Link To A Search Results

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have written this code to enable a search of my database and to then display the results. (code copied below)

I need some help as I need to know how to then create a link from the search results so they can click on the result and it automatically opens the details on a new webpage.

I am very new to PHP so any help anyone can give is appreciated.

Thanks

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
     $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
     if($_POST['filter1'] == "Whole Site"){
         $sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, title AS title FROM cars WHERE title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR description LIKE '%$searchquery%') UNION (SELECT id, title AS title FROM motorcycles WHERE title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR description LIKE '%$searchquery%')";
     } else if($_POST['filter1'] == "cars"){
         $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, title AS title FROM cars WHERE title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR description LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
     } else if($_POST['filter1'] == "motorcycles"){
         $sqlCommand = "SELECT id, title AS title FROM motorcycles WHERE title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR description LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
     }
        include_once("testconn2.php");
        $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
     $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
     if($count > 1){
         $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                 $id = $row["id"];
            $title = $row["title"];
            $search_output .= '<a href="item.php"' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '"?c=$catId&p=' . $id . '">' .$title . '</a><br>';
                } // close while
     } else {
         $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
     }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Search the Database </h2>   <h4><a href="Sign in.php">Sign in</a> <a href="UserRegistration.php">Register</a></h4>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search For: 
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" maxlength="88"> 
Within: 
<select name="filter1">
<option value="Whole Site">Whole Site</option>
<option value="Cars">Cars</option>
<option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit">
<br />
</form>
<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you already have a link to the search results here, correct?

```
 $search_output .= '<a href="item.php"' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '"?c=$catId&p=' . $id . '">' .$title . '</a><br>';
```

You might want to remove the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] or move it before the item.php, as it will append that to your file name, which I am sure you don't want.

Now all you should have to do is create your item.php page, and use $_GET['id'] to get the ID of the item you are looking for.

Once you get the item you are looking for, you can then do a query on your database.

You should also look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) rather than regular mysql commands, as they are not what's recommended to be used nowadays.

For reference to get, you can try [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp) or [PHP's manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks B-RiZzY ill look into the PDP and mysqli. You are correct there is a link to item.php page but the page is blank could you elaberate more on designing my item.php page or maybe an example. would i have to design a page for each item?

Comment: You could use a $_GET parameter to pull an id of the item in your item.php page, and then run your query to get the information of that item from your database. You would not have to design a separate page for each item, as you would use one page to display the information about the item. An example of your URL could be: http://wwww.yoursite.com/item.php?id=123 where 123 would be the item number matching an item in your database. You would then get that id from the URL to use it in your query, in this case: $item_id = $_GET['id']; Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the form method with "get" instead of "post", then when the form is submitted it will generate the link you are looking for.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
```

The link will look like:

```
http://yourwebsite/yourfile.php?searchquery=sometext&fillter1=somevalue1&myBtn=submit
```

Comment: That's not what he was asking. His search results are working fine. He just can't figure out how to generate a page with a single item.

Comment: @B-RiZzY: well, that is what I understood from the question.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses but I don’t think I was very clear with my question…sorry!!  I basically need to create some code that when the item (link) is selected, the existing data is sent to a new page rather than querying the database again.
Is this possible and are there any thoughts about this method rather than creating a separate page? Would this reduce server activity and how safe is it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="item.php"' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '"?c=$catId&p=' . $id . '" taget="_blank">' .$title . '</a><br>';
```

I that part just use the "_blank" target and use $_GET variable in your linked page to show your result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_output .= '<a href="item.php"' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '"?c=$catId&p=' . $id . '">' .$title . '</a><br>';
```

With `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` included outside the double quotes, that looks like it would produce something like

```
<a href="item.php"search.php"?c=1&p=1">Title</a><br>
```

More likely you just want (oh, and encode your ampersands)

```
$search_output .= '<a href="item.php?$catId&amp;p=$id">$title</a><br>';
```